'Object with ID <PAGE ID> does not exist' error in C-URL (Facebook Graph API)
I am currently creating an application which uploads information to Facebook using the Facebook Graph API. However, I am currently facing an error when trying to initialize an upload session.
When I write the following C-URL:
curl -X POST "https://graph.facebook.com/v21.0/<THE PAGE ID>/video_reels" \
    -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
    -d '{{
           "upload_phase:"start",
           "access_token":"<THE ACCESS TOKEN>"
        }}'

I get the error:
{"error":{"message":"Unsupported post request. Object with ID <PAGE ID> does not exist, cannot be loaded due to missing permissions, or does not support this operation. Please read the Graph API documentation at https:\\/\\/developers.facebook.com\\/docs\\/graph-api","type":"GraphMethodException","code":100,"error_subcode":33,"fbtrace_id":"ARVFrHVkhXZTsIN4Lzal-Gb"}}

I have tried to change the permissions on the Facebook account, but when I refresh the page, nothing has changed. Has anybody got an idea what the problem could be?

Neccesary permissions and requirements are listed here, https://developers.facebook.com/docs/video-api/guides/reels-publishing/#before-you-start
